# Uniform underline on spannable string with multiple font sizes?

Tags: android

I have what I think is a simple spanned string question. I have a string like this:

```
    SpannableString styledString = new SpannableString("10:50 PM");//PM is 6-8
    styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(.66f), 6, 8, 0);
    styledString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, 8, 0);
    ((ProgressTextButton)findViewById(R.id.time_button_12)).setText(styledString);
```

It looks like this:

[image: underline issue]

Is there any way to make it so that the underline is uniform?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. My first suggestion would be to simply use another view or a background image on the textView to make the line uniform.

Comment: My guess is that you would need to write a custom replacement for `RelativeSizeSpan` that fiddles with the `baselineShift` field on the `TextPaint`. That doesn't strike me as being very easy.